# Npm Invalid Name: "@angular/compiler"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, ionic2

I am starting to use Ionic2 on a new project and all worked well to get it to install for the first time.

I have now setup a continuous integration build for it and when I am running npm install on the build server it fails with the following:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular/http"
```

ionic info output:

```
Your system information:

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

6.2.0

Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.30
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.16
OS: Windows 8

Node Version: v6.2.1
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ionic-native": "1.2.4",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify-istanbul": "^2.0.0",
    "codecov.io": "^0.1.6",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "isparta": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.5.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "traceur": "0.0.111",
    "ts-node": "^0.9.1",
    "tsify": "^0.16.0",
    "tslint": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "name": "appname",
  "description": "appname: An Ionic project",
  "scripts": {
    "karma": "gulp --gulpfile test/gulpfile.ts --cwd ./ karma-debug",
    "postinstall": "typings install && cp test/karma-static/*.html node_modules/karma/static",
    "test": "gulp --gulpfile test/gulpfile.ts --cwd ./ unit-test",
    "e2e": "gulp --gulpfile test/gulpfile.ts --cwd ./ build-e2e && protractor test/protractor.conf.js",
    "start": "ionic serve",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Node.js solved the problem in my case.